# JSTL getting value in EL from another EL value

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

In my JSP page, I am iterating over a list of objects using the `c:forEach` tag. Each object in this iteration has a name field, and I am trying to use that name field to reference other objects that I have added to my Spring model. However, when I do this, I am getting an exception saying the property of the second object cannot be found on a String. Let me illustrate with a simplified example.

```
<c:forEach items="${companyList}" var="company" varStatus="num">
    <c:set var="monthStats" value="${company.name}_month" />
    <tr>
        <td>Properties This Month</td>
        <td>${monthStats.properties}</td>
    </tr>

    ....

</c:forEach>
```

All of the objects are located inside a Spring Model object and have been set like this
`model.addAttribute(company.getName() +"_month", currentMonthStats);`

I have also tried throwing out the `<c:set` tag and trying

`${(company.name + "_month").properties}`

as well as

`${${company.name + "_month"}.properties}`.

Those havent worked either. Also, I wasn't quite sure how to word my title, so if it could worded better let me know so that other people can find this if they have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically asking for double-evaluation, and it doesn't work like that.

I'd modify the data delivered to the view layer to be something a little less odd, so you can access it in a non-pathological manner, like by putting the month stats into a map accessed by the company name (or id), or directly associated them in a DTO, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking I would have to do something like that. So what is wrong with the double lookup? Im confused why the second loopkup doesn't work if the Model key for the object is a String and that is what I am using to look it up. Does that make sense?

Comment: @jlars62 The `value` is already being evaluated against the object; I just don't think you can use EL inside that expression. I could be mistaken, though; you could check the type of `monthStats` to find out. I'd still consider doing more work before the view layer, though; easier to test and maintain, IMO.